# UE4 - I want to make an ingame camera/photography mode and save the pictures

Tags: c++, camera, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

for my game project I want to include a "camera mode".
This means, that on a press of a button the current camera view gets saved in an in-game gallery.

After some search, I only found ways to save a screenshot on the disk ([BP for saving Screenshot, semi functional](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjD9r.png))
, but I want the picture to be still available in my game, maybe as a texture or in a struct. So I can later use it, well in an in-world picture frame or newspaper.

I did try SceneCaptureComponent2D, but I never got that one really working and searching online got no satisfactory results.

By the way, I'm fine with C++, I'm just building my current prototype with BP for faster testing and altering.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I would have commented on your question, but I do not have enough reputation to do so, because this answer I am providing you is more a hint on how you could do it rather than a straight solution for your problem.

Check out this [repository](https://github.com/TimmHess/UnrealImageCapture) on how to capture images with C++ during a running application which is actually meant for recording data.